# What would happen to the body if it suffered no injuries?

Tags: injury

In this (super cute) animation: '[Jinxy Jenkins & Lucky Lou](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1W-OC7MTCY)' (youtube), the girl, Lucky Lou, is shown to be so lucky, she seems to have never suffered an injury. This is, atleast, what I get the indication of at 1:26 when she looks at her hand in a mixture of confusion and awe.

And this got me thinking, what kind of applications would it have for a human body, to live to about 20-25 without having ANY injuries happen to it? And I mean NONE, not even muscle aches, scraping of hands or knees, no nothing.

I may be wrong in this, but I have perhaps been led to believe that when an injury occours, whilst the body repairs itself, it also goes through some steps to toughen the injured area.

Would the body be noticably more fragile, or would it have virtually no effect?

Comment: It is a myth that injuries toughen your body. Broken bones and scars are not stronger than the original, and neither is any other injury beneficial. Have you heard the saying, "Whatever doesn't kill you makes you stronger"? That's optimistic nonsense. Sometimes what doesn't kill you leaves you paralyzed.